# how to change spark.r.backendConnectionTimeout value?

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

When I use R in Zeppelin it works but when I leave the Zeppelin running one day, next day I get this error for R only:

> sparkR backend is dead, please try to increase spark.r.backendConnectionTimeout

I see from the Spark [configuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#sparkr) that default value is set to 6000 seconds. Does anybody know how to change this value and what value would be useful to keep Zeppelin running all the time? I can use other interpreters (Python, Jdbc, etc.) without having this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use zeppelin 0.8, then you can set it in interpreter setting page.

Comment: hmm, thanks, I did not know I can add configurations in the interpreter settings. But do you know what value would be good? I am not sure if I can put a big value without having other problems.

Comment: It could be any value as large as you want

Comment: I'm experiencing this in Zeppelin 0.10.0; I've set spark.r.backendConnectionTimeout    infinity in the interpreter and restarted the interpreter, but still get the same error.

Any other advice?