# how to change spark.r.backendConnectionTimeout value in RStudio?

Tags: rstudio, sparkr, connection-timeout

I am using RStudio to connect to my HDFS file using SparkR. When I leave Spark analyses running overnight, I get "R session aborted" error the next day. From Spark's documentation on SparkR (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html), the default value of spark.r.backendConnectionTimeout is set to 6000s. I would like to change this value to something large that my connection doesn't time out after the analyses is done.

I have tried the following:

```r
sparkR.session(master = "local[*]", sparkConfig = list(spark.r.backendConnectionTimeout = 10))
sparkR.session(master = "local[*]", spark.r.backendConnectionTimeout = 10)
```

I get the same output for both commands:

```r
Spark package found in SPARK_HOME: C:\Spark\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7
Launching java with spark-submit command C:\Spark\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit2.cmd   sparkr-shell C:\Users\XYZ\AppData\Local\Temp\3\RtmpiEaE5q\backend_port696c18316c61 
Java ref type org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession id 1
```

It seems that the parameter was not passed correctly. Also, I am not sure where to pass that parameter.
Any help would be appreciated.

A similar post is around, but that involves Zeppelin ([how to change spark.r.backendConnectionTimeout value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52651329/how-to-change-spark-r-backendconnectiontimeout-value)).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: it is to modify the spark-defaults.conf file and add the following line:
`spark.r.backendConnectionTimeout = 6000000`

(or whatever time limit you want)

IMPORTANT note - restart hadoop and yarn services, and try connecting to Spark with SparkR normally:

```
library(SparkR, lib.loc = c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib")))
sparkR.session(master = "local")
```

You can check if the settings took place or not at http://localhost:4040/environment/

I hope this comes useful for other people.